# Relation between cumulative distribution of binomials $\Pr[\operatorname{Bin}(n,p)\geq t]\leq \Pr[\operatorname{Bin}(n,q)\geq t]$

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $p<q$ be probabilities, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $t\geq 2n\max\{p,q\}$. I am struggling to prove that

$$\Pr[\operatorname{Bin}(n,p)\geq t]\leq \Pr[\operatorname{Bin}(n,q)\geq t]$$

but I think it should be true. I tried to use induction on $n$ but it didn't work out.

Comment: I won't attempt to answer the question, but I'll note that you can simplify it since $p < q$ means that $\max(p, q) = q$ so $t \geq 2nq$, and by the definition of the binomial distribution the probabilities are trivial if $t \geq n$ (which also means that if $q \geq 0.5$ you've got nothing worth proving).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the inequality is true for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. In other words, $\operatorname{Bin}(n,q)$ [first-order stochastically dominates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance) $\operatorname{Bin}(n,p)$. One technique of proving this inequality is to construct a [coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(probability)) between two distributions.

Indeed, consider independent random variables $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n, Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_n$ such taht

- $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ have $\operatorname{Ber}(q)$ distribution, and
- $Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_n$ have $\operatorname{Ber}(p/q)$ distribution.

Then we find that

- $S_q = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n$ has $\operatorname{Bin}(n,q)$ distribution, and
- $S_p = X_1Y_1 + X_2Y_2 + \cdots + X_nY_n$ has $\operatorname{Bin}(n,p)$ distribution, since $X_iY_i$'s are independent and have $\operatorname{Ber}(p)$ distribution.

Now since $X_iY_i \leq X_i$ always holds, it follows that $S_p \leq S_q$, and hence

$$ \mathbb{P}(\operatorname{Bin}(n,p) \geq t)
= \mathbb{P}(S_p \geq t)
\leq \mathbb{P}(S_q \geq t)
= \mathbb{P}(\operatorname{Bin}(n,q) \geq t). $$

Answer (score 1):

You can use a coupling with $(0,1)$-uniform random variable $U_i \sim_\text{i.i.d} \mathcal{U}(0,1)$, $i = 1, \ldots, n$.

Set $X_i = \mathbf{1}_{U_i < p}$ and $Y_i = \mathbf{1}_{U_i < q}$. Since $p < q$, $X_i \leqslant Y_i$.

Now, $A := X_1 + \cdots + X_n \sim \textrm{Ber}(n,p)$ and $B := Y_1 + \cdots + Y_n \sim \textrm{Ber}(n,q)$. One has $A \leqslant B$, wherefrom you can conclude.

Comment: How could I not come up with this! (+1)